# JsonArray in Scala

Tags: arrays, json, scala, playframework

currently this is what I could get

```
{
    "friends": [438737,
        12345,
        32153,
        53243
    ]
}
```

achievable by doing creating a case class

```
case class FriendsModel(uid: Option[String])
object FriendsModel {
  implicit val paramsWrite = Json.writes[FriendsModel]
  implicit val paramsRead = Json.reads[FriendsModel]
}
```

and basically adding the friendsModel to a List[FriendsModel] called friendList

and I could just `Ok(Json.toJson(friendList))`

Is there a way to insert variable as "friends" so my Json return would look like this:

```
{
    "123654": [438737,
        12345,
        32153,
        53243
    ]
}
```

where 123654 is my userid.

Comment: According to your code, Json.toJson(friends) should return play.api.libs.json.JsValue = [{"uid":"12"},{"uid":"13"},{"uid":"14"}], can you explain how are you getting the output you mentioned

Comment: Sorry, actually it was `case class FriendsModel(uid: Option[MyCustomModel])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would create a case class to encapsulate the data:

```scala
case class User(uid: String, friends: Seq[FriendsModel])
```

and create a Json writer for this type:

```
object User {
  implicit val writer: Writes[User] = Writes { user =>
    Json.obj(
      user.uid -> user.friends
    )
  }
}
```

This will get you `{ "123654": [438737,...] }`

Comment: Every time you want to get rid of field names you will need to implement a custom writer, as stated in this answer

Comment: Thanks! this confirmed the result!